# my company single sign on authentication service is not accepting the request from excel add-in iframe

Tags: authentication, iframe, office365, office-js, excel-addins

my company single sign-on authentication service is not accepting the request from excel add-in iframe.

whenever my excel add-in load's we are requesting the authentication URL but as per my company authentication policy, we shouldn't request from the app which is running inside an Iframe.

what is the alternative for this we have tried excel popup but it is not helping me.

Comment: You'll have to add more details to this question. Why is the popup hasn't been helpful?

Comment: You can embed a browser like CefSharp, Firefox or dotnetbrowser in a win form or wpf window. From there you can redirect the user by opening that window and assigning the appropriate sign in url.